# How to set up textures for a UV tile layout

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, texture-baking

I am exporting textures from substance to blender in a uv tile layout (1001-1005). How do I set each texture to each uv tile?
I tried connecting the textures using the node wrangler but it only placed one image texture. (I've included a picture of what this, it only used the strap texture).

Ive also included pictures of the uv layout in blender and substance as well as what the texture looks like in substance.

I need to know how to connected each uv tile texture  form substance(height, normals, etc.) to each tile in blender.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image files of the tiles must be numbered. E.g. *Body Diffuse.1001.png, Body Diffuse.1002.png, ...*.

In the *Shader Editor*, switch the *Source* (4th combobox) of the *Image Texture* node from *Single Image* (default) to *UDIM Tiles* to use the images as texture.

[image]

In the *Image Editor*, select the image, open the <kbd>N</kbd>-panel, choose the *Image* tab. Make sure *Source* is *UDIM Tiles*. Then you will find above the section *UDIM Tiles* where you can manage the tiles.

[image: UDIM Tiles in Image Editor]